# class does not ge loaded after jquery execution

Tags: jquery

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0xxmtob/1/)

I am using jquery , there are 2 option in select list ,depending on selection ,
 its result appears in `<span id="res"></span>` ,the result concist of input box , one is input type file , and other is  input type text with class='color' , after the result appears in `<span id="res"></span>` it does not load class given in input box . The class is having a property of color picker

.

Comment: adding some code wouldn't break our hearts! :)

Comment: I just added color class to jsfiddle and then when i select the second option, it shows the color. https://jsfiddle.net/o0xxmtob/2/

Comment: i have provided a Working Demo link with code

Comment: @ Vamsi the input box consist of class color is used for color picker

Comment: with use of class color a javascript should be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not the class. Your input has the correct class. The problem is that jsColor needs to be initialized after the element has been created. Add `jscolor.init()` in your else statement.

Check this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o0xxmtob/5/)

Changed code:

```
        else if(choice=='col') {
             //$.getScript("<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL;?>/sinetiks-schools/jscolor/jscolor.js"); 
             $('#res').html("<input class='color' value='66ff00' type='text' name='temp_backg' />") ;
             jscolor.init(); //add this
        }
```

Comment: you r right ,thats what i was expecting , but the demo link u provided is not working completly

Comment: It's missing some images. Just include everything the jsColor comes with in your projects.

Comment: ok, can u tell me where u have done changes or where to put jscolor.init()

Answer (score 0):

Move code in these tags `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` to JavaScript panel. Because otherwise `jscolor` variable is undefined.